# strcmp() function does not compare properly against user input and struct file data

Tags: c++, file, struct, fstream, strcmp

I'm trying to solve this issue where when i try and search for a certain module name in my .dat file, it doesn't show the info of some module like module name, module code.

Example: if I search CSCI124, it shows all of the needed info i need in the output.
However if i try searching for CSCI114 or MATH121, it doesn't show any info except for "Subject Code not found.."

I have tried playing around with not putting in the while loop however it doesn't work as well.

It would be awesome if you guys could help me out, just started learning about c++

```
Subject subjectDB;
char subCode[MAX];
int printOnce = 0;
int position = 0;

cout << "Enter Subject Code: ";
cin >> subCode;

// Open binary file
ifstream fin("Subject.dat", ios::out | ios::binary);

if (!fin)
{
    cout << "\nError opening database..\n"
         << "\tQuitting System..";
    exit(-1);
}

cin.clear();
cin.ignore(100, '\n');

while(fin.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&subjectDB), sizeof(Subject)))
{
    if (!(strcmp(subCode, subjectDB.subjectCode) == 0))
    {
        // Print this section once
        if (printOnce == 0)
        {
            cout << "Subject Code not found..\n";
            printOnce++;
        }
    }

    else
    {
        // Print this section once
        if (printOnce == 0)
        {
            cout << "\nSubject Code: "
                 << subjectDB.subjectCode
                 << "\nSubject Name: "
                 << subjectDB.subjectName
                 << "\n"
                 << endl;

            cout << "Task\t"
                 << "Title\t\t"
                 << "Weight\t"
                 << "Upon\t"
                 << "Mark\t"
                 << "Obtained\n";

            // PrintOnce++ : 1 != 0
            // So it only prints once
            printOnce++;
        }


        cout << position + 1
             << "\t"
             << subjectDB.assessment[position].title
             << "\t"
             << subjectDB.assessment[position].weight
             << "\t"
             << subjectDB.assessment[position].upon
             << "\t"
             << subjectDB.assessment[position].taskMark
             << "\t"
             << "testing\n";

             position++;
    }   
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use `std::string`?

Comment: What is `Subject`? How is it declared? What is `subjectCode`? You do know that [`std::strcmp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcmp) is case-sensitive?

Comment: show the definition of `Subject` and also your input file. To help debug this problem you could output the two things you're strcmping.

Comment: Subject is a structure, here is the layout.

struct Subject
{
 char subjectCode[MAX];
 char subjectName[MAX];
 int numberOfAssessmentTask;
 AssessmentTask assessment[MAX];
 int finalMark;
 Grade grade;
};

subjectCode is the variable inside the structure. and yes i know that strcmp is case sensitive.

do i have to use the std:: when i have alrdy included the cstdlib in my codes?

Answer (score 0):

Writing a struct to a file or reading a struct from a file is totally non-portable. Compile the same code on two different compilers, or on the same compiler with different settings, and what you wrote and what you read might be very different. That's not necessarily your problem, but it will be your problem one day.

Answer (score 0):

Your display code logic is flawed.

**Explanation:**

If the subject code is in the first record you read, you'll get the correct answer.  However as soon as your fist record does not match,  the "Not found" message is displayed, printOnce is incremented.  If the matching subject coe is found later in the file printOnce is no longer 0 and it' will not be displayed.

**Solution:**

Organise your loop in the opposite way:

```
while (...)  {
    if (strcmp(..)==0) {
         // your code to display the found item here
         printOnce++;
         break; // ?? optional: you could stop the loop at first found occurence unless you suppose there could be duplicates
    }
}
```

and once the loop is finished, check OUTSIDE OF THE LOOP if you've found something:

```
   if (printOnce==0) { // nothing was found in the loop 
          // display that nothing was found !  
   }
```

**Remark:**

Reading directly from file as you do has limitations.  It can only work with plain old data (POD), not with more advanced types using `string` members or containters.  For learning it's a good start but I'd suggest to foresee a `Subject` member function that loads the data from a stream. This proves to be more flexible when your data structure evolves: the member function could ealsily read each member data and sub-objects using the most apporpriate way.

Comment: I've tried your suggested solution however the problem still persist.
I am able to get the full info on a module name CSCI114, however for the rest it shows partial information, it says "Subject Code not found..." and then the module result mark percentage will show.

Comment: for loading of data, is it the streambuf() function? Sorry i'm not quite good in c++ like the file stream etc, did a sudden change of language from 3 years of learning java to c++

Comment: Did you do the "not found" check outside the loop ?  If yes, I'd recommend that you display each `subjectDB.subjectCode`you read and the result of strcmp(), in ordr to make sure that your issue does not come from the content of the file or the way you read it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help! I managed to get the function to compare properly against user input and struct file by creating a function that checks the .dat file if the subject is existing or not.

```
int row = checkNumberOfData(fileName);

if (row > 0)
    exist = doesSubjectExist(file, fileName, code);  // checks input 

if (!exist)
{
    file.open(fileName, ios::out | ios::app | ios::binary);

    if (!file)
    {
        cout << "Error opening database..\n"
             << "\tQuitting System ..\n";
        exit(-1);
    }

    strcpy(subjectDB.code, code);

    cout << "Subject Name: ";
    cin.getline(subjectDB.name, MAX);

    cout << "No of assessment tasks: ";
    cin >> subjectDB.num;
    cout << endl;
    .... etc
```

}